# change in property value not triggering change detection in angular4

Tags: angular

I am currently trying to implement disabling the Add button based on setting the property in the component in my angular 4 application. I am possibly having issue with change detection. It works some time but some times doesn't. I assume that setting the property in the component code should trigger change detection automatically. I basically need to disable the Add and the drop-down when editing the Lob and enable the Add button and drop-down while saving. Could somebody tell me what the problem could be

In the code below i am trying to disable the Add button (second div element) as well as the drop down (First div element) using the code `[disabled]="isOpenLob"`.

> Component.html code

```
<div class="mt-4 col-sm-6 only-ie">
    <select [disabled]="isOpenLob" class="select-wrapper" [(ngModel)]="selectedLineOfBusiness" name="linesOfBusiness">
        <option disabled="disabled" [ngValue]="defaultLineOfBusiness">Test</option>
        <option class="theme--option--default" *ngFor="let lob of linesOfBusiness" [ngValue]="lob">Test</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="mt-4 col-sm-2">
    <button href="javascript:void(0);" [disabled]="isOpenLob" (click)="add()" type="button" class="col-12 btn btn-primary">Test</button>
</div>



<div>
         <table class="table table-list">
              <thead class="lob-thead">
                <tr>
                  <th class="column-sort">{{'NAME'|translate}}</th>
                  <th class="column-sort">{{'LABEL'|translate}}</th>
                  <th class="column-sort">{{'STRUCTURE'|translate}}</th>
                  <th class="column-sort">{{'LOB'|translate}}</th>
                  <th class="column-sort hidden-md-down min-width">{{'PREMIUM'|translate}}</th>
                  <th class="column-sort hidden-md-down">{{'PAYOUTFACTORS'|translate}}</th>
                  <th class="column-sort hidden-md-down min-width">{{'INCEXPENSE'|translate}}</th>
                  <th class="column-sort hidden-md-down">{{'COMMERCIALPREMIUM.LABEL'|translate}}</th>
                  <th class="column-sort hidden-md-down">{{'BUSINESSCEDED'|translate}}</th>
                  <th class="column-sort"></th>
                  <th class="column-sort"></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <ng-template let-row let-i="index" ngFor [ngForOf]="this.run.linesOfBusinessInput">
                  <tr app-lob-item [ngClass]="{'tr--opacity': selectedIndex !== -1, 'active': selectedIndex === i, 'complete': row.completed, 'incomplete': !row.completed}"
                    [lob]="row" [modelTypes]="run.referenceData.modelTypes" [linesOfBusiness]="linesOfBusiness" [index]="i"
                    (deleteEvent)="delete($event)" (copyEvent)="copy($event)" (editEvent)="edit($event)"></tr>
                      <ng-template [ngIf]="selectedIndex === i">
                          <tr app-lob-item-detail class="hidden" [domicile]="this.run?.referenceData?.domiciles" [lob]="row" [editableLob]="editableLob" [index]="i" [show]="selectedIndex === i"
                          [policyTypes]="run.referenceData.policyTypes" [lobNames]="lobNames" [modelTypeOptions]="run.referenceData.modelTypeOptions" [modelTypes]="run.referenceData.modelTypes"
                          (cancelEvent)="cancel($event)" (saveEvent)="save($event)"></tr>
                      </ng-template>
                </ng-template>
              </tbody>
</div>
```

> Component.ts code

```
private _isOpenLob: boolean;

get isOpenLob(): boolean {
    return this._isOpenLob;
}

edit(index: number) {
    this._isOpenLob = true;
    this.lobNames = this.run.linesOfBusinessInput.map(x => x.id);
    this.selectedIndex = index;
    this.editableLob = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.run.linesOfBusinessInput[this.selectedIndex]));
    this.changeTracker.commit();
}


save(event: any) {
    this._isOpenLob = false;
    this.run.linesOfBusinessInput[event.index] = event.lob;
    this._persist();
    if (event.closeLob) {
        this.selectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling your functions ? I don't see them being called

Comment: you can see the isOpenLob() is called in the html. The private variable this._isOpenLob = false; is being set in the save method

Comment: Yet but to fix it to true you have to call `edit`and I don't see it being called.

Comment: i didnt get what you mean.  this._isOpenLob = true; is first line of code in the edit method

Comment: And where is the `edit` method called ?

Comment: I have added the html code that calls the edit method

Comment: So when i set the debug points on save and edit methods it gets called when edit and save button are clicked respectively

Comment: Did you try with removing the getter and making the variable public ?

Comment: Yes when that was inconistent, i changed it property thinking that property would trigger change detection correctly

Comment: Okay, last question, are you sure both `edit` and `save` aren't run at the same time ? (check that with console logs)

Comment: I can see while editing the save method is triggered as well. Not sure why

Comment: There is your issue. I can't really tell you why, but I hope this helped you !

Comment: (And since you've found the issue, I suggest you either provide a [mcve] or delete your question, as it will help you only).